# Does a table do work holding a book?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Suppose I keep a book on the table. Is the table doing any work in stopping it from falling down? No right? because the displacement is zero?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe confused because you are putting yourself in the place of the table while imagining this. That's empathy and quite ok.

You would get tired and spend energy holding a book like that for a while. But it's because of the way your muscles work. The muscles are not "locked" in constant shape.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I keep a book on the table.

Ok ...

> Is the table doing any work in stopping it from falling down?

No.

> No right? because the displacement is zero?

Yup.